# Why Github is failing to load resources from my jekyll project?

Tags: github, yaml, jekyll

I hope someone can help me to figure this out since i've been trying several thing throughout the day and I still couldn't find the root of this issue. The github is failing to load the jekyll content... giving me several error at every attempt... I searched for similar issues here and i also modified my yml file in the url as suggested in other posts but with no success. If someone could help me i would appreciate since i just literally lost atm. tia 
 https://github.com/CarlasHub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRcGU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In ***_config.yml***, set :

```
baseurl: "/carlashub"
url: "https://CarlasHub.github.io"
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for your help that partial solved since its not showing up the 404 only, but is not loading my sass :( i dont really know where the problem is... if you have any hint please lemme know https://carlashub.github.io/carlashub/

Answer (score 0):

Have you set Github Pages up in the settings within the Github repo?

goto --

> Settings > Options > *Scroll down* > GitHub Pages

Make sure you have selected the source, this will generate a CNAME file in your repo which will contain the URL. After a short while, you will be able to see your site.

Below is an example of the config.yaml I use on most of my projects.

```
title: Site Title
url: "https://domainame.com"
baseurl: /
google_analytics_key: 

email:
description:  Test stuff.

# Build settings
paginate:       5
paginate_path:  "/blog/:num/"
permalink:      pretty

markdown:       kramdown
permalink:      /:title/

sass:
  style: compressed

plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock

plugins:        [jekyll-paginate]
```